# Joining two tables and keep dissimilar values

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, join, left-join, sqlfiddle

I have two tables, child and parent, that I want to join it. Child table include fields that are not similar to the ones in parent table. Please find tables structure below:

SiteTable:

```
Site    | SiteName
----------------------
1         London
2         Paris
3         NY
```

AssetsTable:

```
ID      | Site
----------------------
A         1
B         1
C         2
D         3
E         5
F         Null
```

I want to join these two tables and get this result:

```
ID      | SiteName
----------------------
A         London
B         London
C         Paris
D         NY
E         5
F         Null
```

I tried following code:

```
SELECT a.ID, s.SiteName 
FROM AssetsTable a LEFT JOIN SiteTable s on (s.site = a.site)
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aa7b2/2/0)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ISNULL` for `SQL` and `IFNULL` for mysql

```
select a.ID, ISNULL(s.SiteName,a.Site) 
FROM AssetsTable a LEFT JOIN SiteTable s on (s.site = a.site)
```

Check [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aa7b2/6)